# How to upgrade Ubuntu via ISO file?

Tags: upgrade, iso, lts

How can I upgrade Ubuntu 18.04(LTS) to 19.xx , using an [iso](http://releases.ubuntu.com/19.10/ubuntu-19.10-desktop-amd64.iso) file?

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! Please note there are no “Ubuntu 18” or “Ubuntu 19”. Please [use full version numbers when talking about Ubuntu releases](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17941/always-use-full-ubuntu-version-numbers-if-you-want-to-specify-the-version).

Comment: Ubuntu server & desktop releases which rely on debian based files use the *yy.mm* format, where as snap based releases do actually use a *yy* format however these are only released in even years.  There is no Ubuntu 18 or 19, nor any `ubuntu-19.iso` image, so you've likely got a forgery and not an official Ubuntu image - so beware!

Comment: Ubuntu *yy.mm* releases are only tested to upgrade from one release to the next, OR from one LTS to the next LTS.  Thus for example, if you were on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, you have two options, (1) to the next release or 18.10, or (2) to the next LTS release which will be Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (but only after 20.04.1 has been released).  Other upgrade paths are untested & unsupported.  I'm referring currently to *yy.mm* or deb based releases only.

Answer (score 4):

There is no upgrade path for Ubuntu through the ISO. The options you have are

1. overwrite the current OS.
2. add the new OS on an empty partition.

Next: there is no Ubuntu 18 or Ubuntu 19. It is Ubuntu 18.04 and Ubuntu 19.10. 19.04 has gone end of life on 23rd January 2020 so there is currently no official upgrade path to 19.10.

For an upgrade from 18.04 you will need to wait for Ubuntu 20.04.1.

If you really need 19.10 (and I wonder why as it will go end of life July, 2020) you need to re-install. So create a personal backup, install 19.10 and restore your files. 
I would wait for 20.04.1 and upgrade to that LTS.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest and easiest way is to re-install using '*something-else*' (or "*Manual/Manual Partitioning*" with how it appears varying on release & flavor used) and install over your existing partitions.

1. Use manual partitioning
2. select existing partitions, ensuring 'format' checkbox is unticked
3. the installer will note your installed software
4. it'll erase system directories (as long as 'format' was unticked)
5. install system (from booted ISO)
6. it'll add back your prior packages if available on your new release (this will require internet access as they're downloaded)
7. user files are not touched (unless 'format' was ticked/checked)
8. user is asked to reboot.

This allows you to skip releases, and is pretty faster (far faster than a *release-upgrade*) It can be used to re-install the same release, or a different release or flavor.  It's great for desktops, though as some server apps store config/settings in system directories, some server applications will required restoring data after completion; this issue won't impact desktop releases as they stored configs in $HOME or /home/$USER/ directories which aren't touched (as long as format wasn't checked).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to upgrade Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to 19.10:

1. You need to edit file `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades`

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
   ```

   Just change `Prompt=lts` to `Prompt=normal`
2. Then run

   ```
   do-release-upgrade -p
   ```

You must have enough space in `/boot`.

I tried this on virtual machine and it worked for my case.

Comment: IIRC you'll encounter an error: `Upgrade to Eoan from Bionic isn't supported`.