# How to upgrade Ubuntu Desktop 18.0.4 LTS to 20.0.4 LTS from DVD?

Tags: upgrade, 20.04, lts, dvd

A friend of mine has Ubuntu Desktop 18.0.4 LTS installed and would like to upgrade to 20.0.4 LTS.  He has tried repeatedly to do so in the recommended way (from repositories), but his Internet connection is not stable enough.  I have burned an installation DVD for him, but on testing it, I see that the startup menu no longer includes an upgrade option, only "try" and "install".  All of the instructions and posts I have found for recent versions of Ubuntu assume that it can be done online. How can an upgrade be performed from an installation DVD?

Comment: You can install using *something else*, select your existing partitions, and if you don't format the partitions, it will note your installed packages, erase system directories, install new system, then attempt to add back your additional packages (if available on the new release) from the internet. As long as you don't format, it won't touch user files. As some server applications can stored config files in system directories, this works better for desktop systems (which store config files in $HOME which isn't touched unless you format).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upgrade Ubuntu via ISO file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219468/how-to-upgrade-ubuntu-via-iso-file)